# TypeORM QueryBuilder should return most recent inner joined record

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to get most recent transaction by using this query inside my NestJs application

```
  public findUsersWithRecentTransactions(): Promise<UserEntity[]> {
    return this.createQueryBuilder('users')
      .innerJoinAndSelect('users.transactions', 'transactions')
      .where(
        '(users.userType = :userTypeParent AND users.registrationStatus = :registrationStatusParent)',
        {
          userTypeParent: UserType.Parent,
          registrationStatusParent: RegistrationStatus.onboarded,
        },
      )
      .orderBy('transactions.created_at', 'DESC').getMany();
  }
```

This returns an array of transactions sorted by their created_at date in descending order. However, I am trying to get the most recent transaction using the query itself so that I don't have to loop over the entities to get the transaction.

```
const usersWithTransactions = await this.userRepository.findAllUsersWithTransactions();
    for (const user of usersWithTransactions) {
      const mostRecentTransaction = user?.transactions[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should try limit method.

```
  public findUsersWithRecentTransactions(): Promise<UserEntity[]> {
    return this.createQueryBuilder('users')
      .innerJoinAndSelect('users.transactions', 'transactions')
      .where(
        '(users.userType = :userTypeParent AND users.registrationStatus = :registrationStatusParent)',
        {
          userTypeParent: UserType.Parent,
          registrationStatusParent: RegistrationStatus.onboarded,
        },
      )
      .orderBy('transactions.created_at', 'DESC')
      .limit(1) // I include this.
      .getMany();
  }
```

Check this code above. I added '.limit(1)'.